# How do I know when kendo treeview has finished loading?

Tags: events, kendo-ui, treeview

I'm trying the Kendo Ui framework. I'm working on a treeview.

I need to know if there is an event that is raised when it is finished loading the complete treeview. I'm using a call json.

Answer (score 0):

Loading it or rendering it? It is similar but not the same, first you need to load the data and only then it starts rendering the loaded items.

For loading you might use [`dataBound`](http://docs.kendoui.com/api/web/treeview#events-dataBound) in the `TreeView`